# Grabbing plain text from a website and displaying on another website

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, iframe

I am a developer working on a website, `example.html`. 
I have a friend who is not good at HTML and I need him to do some work that will be uploaded automatically on `example.com.` For example, if I enter text on `abc.com` (plain text), the software will grab the text automatically and transfer it onto my website. Is there any way to do this? 
`<iframe>` and `<object>`tags are allowed. However, HTML, CSS and Javascript only please. And if possible, the software should be easily embedded. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some sort of back-end (server)?

Comment: Yes server and `abc.com` are already provided. The question is how the text will be transferred.

Comment: What type of back-end do you have? What language would you use PHP, C#, Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [PostMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) for passing messages between parent and child iframes which works cross domain